# Why path.subtracted(path2) is linking my path? How can I delinking?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt5, pyqt5

I am working on a simple Paint application using pyqt5. My goal is:

**1**. Draw freely according to mouse events. It's done!

**2**. Erase freely according to mouse events. It isn't work as expected!

I have a QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene where I'm adding QGraphicsItems, specifically QGraphicsPathItem. My eraser has a rect shape, and what I want is to erase part of my drawing while moving my eraser on it.

On MouseMoveEvent, I check if my eraser shape intersects my drawing path, if so, I just subtract it from my drawing path. Then the awkward behavior occurs, it closes my drawing path.

Figure_1, shows my drawing (QGraphicsPathItem). 
Figure_2, shows what happens when my eraser(QGraphicsRectItem) intersects my drawing.

[Drawing freely lines working fine. Figure_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAgiM.png)

[Erasing drawing. Figure_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFNSR.png)

As we can see, it draws a line linking my first and end points, closing my path. I dont want it. I just want to erase my drawing path.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, \
    QGraphicsView, QPushButton, QWidget, \
    QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsPathItem, QGraphicsRectItem

class Window(QWidget):
    scene = None

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.view = View(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Clear View', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleClearView)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleClearView(self):
        self.view.scene.clear()


class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.scribing = False
        self.erasing = False
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.free_draw_item = None
        self.eraser_item = None

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        self.setSceneRect(QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.scribing = True
            pp = QPainterPath(event.pos())

            self.free_draw_item = QGraphicsPathItem(pp)
            self.free_draw_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.green))
            self.free_draw_item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

            self.free_draw_item.setPath(pp)
            self.scene.addItem(self.free_draw_item)

        if event.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.erasing = True
            self.eraser_item = QGraphicsRectItem(event.pos().x() - 5,
                                                 event.pos().y() - 5, 10, 10)
            self.eraser_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))
            self.eraser_item.setBrush(Qt.transparent)
            self.scene.addItem(self.eraser_item)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribing:
            if self.free_draw_item:
                path = self.free_draw_item.path()
                path.lineTo(event.pos())
                self.free_draw_item.setPath(path)

        if event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton and self.erasing:

            self.eraser_item.setRect(event.pos().x() - 5, event.pos().y() - 5,
                                     10, 10)

            for item in self.scene.collidingItems(self.eraser_item):
                if isinstance(item, QGraphicsPathItem):

                    if item.path().intersected(self.eraser_item.shape()):
                        new = item.path().subtracted(self.eraser_item.shape())
                        item.setPath(new)
                        #item.setBrush(Qt.red)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.scribing = False
        self.erasing = False

        if self.eraser_item != None:
            self.scene.removeItem(self.eraser_item)
        # if self.free_draw_item != None:
        #     self.free_draw_item.setSelected(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is my code.

Left mouse button draws green path on scene.

Right mouse button erase my drawings.

Comment: There is nothing out of the box. You have to keep your path as sub paths, and recreate it upon modifying the sub-paths.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem several and several times.

After some headache and a thousand unsuccessful researches about this specific problem I've come to on answer.

1. Forget having only one path
2. You cant subtract without closing the path turning it into a closed polygon
3. Think as having many paths and working around
4. Now you have all sub items and can "delete" them when colliding with your eraser
5. Use the subtract on your favor
6. Have many paths with 3 not align points each path(least points on a plan to have a polygon)
7. Group it as QGraphicsItemGroup() if you want to manipulate the whole path made of several (3 points path) as a single item
8. See my example

-

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, \
    QGraphicsView, QPushButton, QWidget, \
    QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsPathItem, QGraphicsRectItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItemGroup

from core.IQGraphicsPathItem import InteractQGraphicsPathItem


class Window(QWidget):
    scene = None



    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.view = View(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Clear View', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleClearView)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleClearView(self):
        self.view.scene.clear()


class View(QGraphicsView):

    dic = {}
    num_item = 0
    _from_x_ = None
    _from_y_ = None
    pp = None

    pen = None

    group = None

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.scribing = False
        self.erasing = False
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.free_draw_item = QGraphicsPathItem()
        # self.free_draw_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.green))
        # self.free_draw_item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.eraser_item = None
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.green,8)
        self.pen.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green))
        self.pen.setWidth(1)

        self.group = QGraphicsItemGroup()

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        self.setSceneRect(QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._from_x_ = event.pos().x()
            self._from_y_ = event.pos().y()

            self.scribing = True

            self.group = QGraphicsItemGroup()
            self.group.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            self.scene.addItem(self.group)

            self.pp = QPainterPath(event.pos())

            self.free_draw_item = QGraphicsPathItem(self.pp)
            self.free_draw_item.setPen(self.pen)
            # self.free_draw_item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

            self.free_draw_item.setPath(self.pp)
            self.scene.addItem(self.free_draw_item)
            self.group.addToGroup(self.free_draw_item)


        if event.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.erasing = True
            self.eraser_item = QGraphicsRectItem(event.pos().x() - 5,
                                                 event.pos().y() - 5, 10, 10)
            self.eraser_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))
            self.eraser_item.setBrush(Qt.white)
            self.scene.addItem(self.eraser_item)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        x_adjust = 1
        y_adjust = 1

        # if event.pos().x() >= self._from_x_:
        #     x_adjust = 1
        # else:
        #     x_adjust = -1
        # if event.pos().y() >= self._from_y_:
        #     y_adjust = 1
        # else:
        #     y_adjust = -1



        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribing:
            if self.free_draw_item:

                # path = self.free_draw_item.path()
                # path.lineTo(event.pos())
                # self.free_draw_item.setPath(path)

                self.pp2 = QPainterPath(QPoint(self._from_x_, self._from_y_))
                self.pp2.lineTo(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
                self.pp2.lineTo(event.pos().x()+x_adjust, event.pos().y()+y_adjust)
                self.pp2.lineTo(self._from_x_ + x_adjust, self._from_y_ + y_adjust)
                self.free_draw_item.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 8))
                self.free_draw_item.path = QGraphicsPathItem()
                self.free_draw_item.path.setPath(self.pp2)
                self.scene.addItem(self.free_draw_item.path)
                self.group.addToGroup(self.free_draw_item)

                self._from_x_ = event.pos().x()
                self._from_y_ = event.pos().y()

        if event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton and self.erasing:

            self.eraser_item.setRect(event.pos().x() - 5, event.pos().y() - 5,
                                     10, 10)

            for item in self.scene.collidingItems(self.eraser_item):

                new = item.path() - self.eraser_item.shape()
                item.setPath(new)
                print('collided')



    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.scribing = False
        self.erasing = False

        self.group.setSelected(True)
        print(self.scene.items())

        if self.eraser_item != None:
            self.scene.removeItem(self.eraser_item)

        # if self.free_draw_item != None:
        #     self.free_draw_item.setSelected(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to personalize your own Pen I suggest you to overwrite your own QGraphicsPathItem().

I think it'll work pretty great.